# Troubles with selecting the lastes record from Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have got some problems with selecting the lastest record (the last one that got imported)
When i try to Select lasted record from one table, it does not select really the last one
for example, if i just run now this:

```
SELECT * FROM Lat ORDER BY Lat DESC LIMIT 1
```

it will give me the output 'XX.34148035' instead of 'XX.34142197'(When i manualy go to the last page (7) in PMA, i see XX.34142197...)

So my idea was to check the A_I option and selecting the Highest ID.
Then run a query again,

```
SELECT * FROM Lat ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

This time it works, yay.
So now i did the exact same thing to the other table, but when i run the query:

```
SELECT * FROM (Lat, Lng) ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

I get an error:

```
Column 'ID' in order clause is ambiguous
```

With i can understand, but no idea to fix...
After this i became stuck, googled alot but its very confusing...
If somebody could help me, or give me a hint it would be very nice...
Also, i have discovered that when i use

```
SELECT * FROM Lat,Lng
```

The output is:

```
+-----+-------------+-----+------------+
| ID  | Lat         | ID  | Lng        |
+-----+-------------+-----+------------+
|   1 | XX.34123183 |   1 | XX.64095977 |
|   2 | XX.34128739 |   1 | XX.64095977 |
|   3 | XX.3412688  |   1 | XX.64095977 |
|   4 | XX.34127248 |   1 | XX.64095977 |
|   5 | XX.34126652 |   1 | XX.64095977 |
|   6 | XX.3412708  |   1 | XX.64095977 |
|   7 | 52.34127314 |   1 | XX.64095977 |
|//some record laters....(yes 181 is last)
| 179 | XX.34145865 |   1 | XX.64095977 |
| 180 | 52.34144137 |   1 | XX.64095977 |
| 181 | XX.34142197 |   1 | XX.64095977 |
|   1 | XX.34123183 |   2 | XX.64226005 |
|   2 | XX.34128739 |   2 | XX.64226005 |
|   3 | XX.3412688  |   2 | XX.64226005 |
|   4 | XX.34127248 |   2 | XX.64226005 |
```

With i thought that it would be more like this...

```
+-----+-------------+   +-----+-------------+
| ID  | Lat         |   | ID  | Lng         |
+-----+-------------+   +-----+-------------+
|   1 | XX.34123183 |   |   1 | XX.32535611  |
|   2 | XX.34128739 |   |   2 | XX.32565655  |
|   3 | XX.3412688  |   |   3 | XX.32525515  |
|   4 | XX.34127248 |   |   4 | XX.325255555 |
```

What im doing wrong here?

Thanks already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    lat
        JOIN
    lng USING (id)
ORDER BY lat.id DESC
```

try this. You want to join the tables

Answer (score 0):

When two or more tables are involved in a query and those tables contain same column names, you need to specify which table's column you are operating on.  The ambiguity is because both `Lat` and `Lng` table contain column `ID` and the query processor does not know which `ID` to use to order the results.

For example, to order by `Lat` table's `ID` column, you'd specify `Lat.ID` as:

```
SELECT * FROM (Lat, Lng) ORDER BY Lat.ID DESC LIMIT 1
```